# JQuery object seems to not be assigned a value in module

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

```
 var Foo = Foo || {};

Foo.Controller = (function ($) {
    var $page = $("#bar");
    var init = function () {
            console.log($page); // outputs: []
            console.log($.isEmptyObject($page)); // outputs: false
        }
    var public = {
        init: init
    }
    return public;
})(jQuery);
$("#FooPage").bind("pageinit", function () {
    Foo.Controller.init();
});
```

Why does $page not seem to be assigned its value? 
I am using JQuery Mobile and the pageinit is the mobile equivalent of document ready.

Comment: Does an element with an id attribute of `bar` exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$page` is not assigned on `pageinit`, it is assigned immediately. Try this:

```
var init = function () {
    console.log($page); // outputs: []
    console.log($('#bar'); // TELL US IF THIS LOGS THE RIGHT THING!
    console.log($.isEmptyObject($page)); // outputs: false
};
```

**EDIT (Esailija pointed out another issue):**

Esailija has much better eyes than I. `Foo.Controller` is set to the result of the [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). Since that function doesn't return anything, it is set to `undefined`. Maybe you want to return an object that has your `init` function? In that case, you can avoid the entire problem by setting `$page` inside of `init`.

```
var Foo = Foo || {};

Foo.Controller = (function($) {
    var init = function () {
        var $page = $("#bar");
        console.log($page); // outputs: []  <-- not anymore (if #bar is really on the page)
        console.log($.isEmptyObject($page)); // outputs: false
    };
    return {init:init};
})(jQuery);
$("#FooPage").bind("pageinit", function () {
    Foo.Controller.init();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're deferring the *call* to `.init`, the immediately invoked function expression that's (supposed to be) creating the `init` function defines `var $page = $("#bar");` before the page is loaded.